# Android google map capture the camera position only after it stops

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am creating an Android app with Google Maps. I need to draw ~ 100.000 markers on the map, so I draw only in the visible area.

But I have a problem: onCameraMove () catches all changes all the time, but I only need to catch if the camera has stopped completely.

How to do it?

```
override fun onCameraMove() {
//here i catch visible region and draw markers near it.
}
```

Comment: Sorry not understandable exactly, can you please elaborate little more and show your efforts also.

Comment: When user move camera, fun onCameraMove() calls on every pixel of move (i think) - so many times, that my server drop down. I need to call this function only when camera stop moving.

Comment: Actually it is a abstract method you can't control this method and not able to stop calling this method. You need to manage variable to calling your code.

Comment: But how can I create a method that will only be called when the camera stops moving? How can i check camera movings?

Comment: Sorry! but i don't think so there is any method like this. What you exactly doing in that method?

Comment: I'm get latitude and longitude center of visible region
latS = mMap?.getProjection()?.getVisibleRegion()?.latLngBounds?.center?.latitude.toString()

After it, I'm send post method with lat and long to server, and it send me array list with markers in this area.

Comment: No have no exact solution but you can try one thing. The lat lng getting from this method store in global variable. Now call your api in every 10 sec. So you will get solution and stop too much load on your server. And the api call in 10 sec can handle more then 5 lac users simultaneous because i have experience of this.

Comment: Ok, thx a lot. But how I can pick your comment like answer?

Comment: You can up my comment. So if any other will face same issue can apply this method

Comment: I can't. I think this is because my reputation is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lat lng getting from this method store in global variable. Now call your api in every 10 sec. So you will get solution and stop too much load on your server.